# File Input within a Dialog cause Dialog to close when File Input is cancelled

Tags: javascript, forms, file, input, dialog

The issue here is that I have a Dialog and within the Dialog I have File Input.

When I open the File Input and hit Cancel, it will also close the Dialog as well, which is not the behaviour I'm looking for.

```
<dialog open>
  <p>My Dialog</p>
  <form method="dialog">
    <input type="file" />
  </form>
</dialog>
```

Here is a JSFiddle to showcase the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/aumntbo0/)

I've tried stopping the propigation of click and cancel events, but the behaviour still persist, which leads me to believe there is something else at play that is causing this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Behaviors of the file input and other native html elements is sometimes tough to customize, and usually for pretty valid reasons (security, user expectations, accessibility). Here is a way to specifically prevent this behavior, but in my opinion it is a silly one because it will prevent you from closing the dialogue at all. You could customize the code to only prevent the dialog element from closing in certain situations.

```
<dialog id='file-dialog' open>
  <p>My Dialog</p>
  <form method="dialog">
    <input type="file" />
  </form>
</dialog>
```

JavaScript:

```
const dialog = document.getElementById('file-dialog')
dialog.addEventListener('close', (event) => {
    dialog.open = true;
});
```

Your best might be to not use a dialog element, but not sure your use case.